# How to access a function from an outside class in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, function, access-specifier

I'm trying to access a function which belongs to a Class frmamain from another class. please can anyone tell me how i have to achieve this? i'm new to VB.NET. thanks in advance.

The code throws the following error

*"ConvertImagerBnW() is not declared. it may be inaccessible due to its protection level"*

```
class frmamain
Public Function ConvertImagerBnW()

    Try
        Dim img As Bitmap = New Bitmap((Image.FromFile("D:\\imgnam.jpg")))
        ''Dim img As Bitmap = New Bitmap(ImageBox1.Image)
        Dim c As Color
        Dim i As Integer = 0
        Do While (i < img.Width)
            Dim j As Integer = 0
            Do While (j < img.Height)
                c = img.GetPixel(i, j)
                Dim r As Integer = 0
                r = Convert.ToInt16(c.R)
                Dim g As Integer = 0
                g = Convert.ToInt16(c.G)
                Dim b As Integer = 0
                b = Convert.ToInt16(c.B)
                Dim ans As Integer = ((r _
                            + (g + b)) _
                            / 3)
                If (ans > 128) Then
                    r = 255
                    g = 255
                    b = 255
                Else
                    r = 0
                    g = 0
                    b = 0
                End If
                c = Color.FromArgb(r, g, b)
                img.SetPixel(i, j, c)
                j = (j + 1)
            Loop
            i = (i + 1)
        Loop
        ''Image<Gray, Byte> normalizedimg = new Image<Gray, Byte>(img);
        img.Save("D:\\imgnamNew.jpg")
        Dim Bmp1 As New Image(Of Bgr, [Byte])("D:\\imgnamNew.jpg")
        ImageFrame = Bmp1
        ''ImageBox1.Image = ImageFrame
        ''ImageBox1.Image.Save("D:\\imgnamNew.jpg")
        '' MessageBox.Show("SUCESSFULLY DONE")
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    End Try

End Function
end class


Module UseThread
    Sub newthread()
      ConvertImagerBnW()
    End Sub
End Module
```

Comment: Make the access of the method public....

Comment: ***"I am new in VB.Net"*** We need to see what you wrote so far... it looks like the issue is not related with .net but with SoftDevel...

Comment: yes i have made same changes but not works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ConvertImagerBnW` is a member of the `frmamain` class so you have to actually call it on an instance of that class.  This:

```
Module UseThread
    Sub newthread()
      ConvertImagerBnW()
    End Sub
End Module
```

doesn't know anything about `frmamain`.  At it's simplest, you need to do something like this:

```
Module UseThread
    Sub newthread()
      frmamain.ConvertImagerBnW()
    End Sub
End Module
```

That will call that method on the default instance of `frmamain`, assuming that it's a form.  If it's not the default instance or it's not a form then you need to access an instance form somewhere.  That might look like this:

```
Module UseThread
    Sub newthread()
      Dim obj As New frmamain

      obj.ConvertImagerBnW()
    End Sub
End Module
```

If you want to call the method on an existing instance rather than a new instance then you'd have to get a reference to that instance from somewhere.  Exactly how you would do that depends on the specifics of your project.

Comment: Thanks to all for replying me it works. @jmcilhinney